# C# culture info/setting up a specific tostring for currency

Tags: c#, tostring, cultureinfo

I'm looking to make a customer decimal format. What I get right now if I do "(3003.3003d).ToString(#,###.00##") is "3,003.3003". What I am trying to get as a format would be "3'003.300,3".

I can use a customer method, math.floor and break it apart myself, but I'm curious if there is a way to use culture info to do what I am looking for. Anyone know of a way to do that?

Wrote the guy with custom IFormatprovider as the answer as the tutorial was pretty good, but I do not believe a current culture exists with what I needed. Here was my end answer :

```
private string ToCustomDecimal(decimal Input, int MaxLenPostDec, int MinLenPostDec)
    {
        string CustD;
        string[] Split = Input.ToString().Split('.');
        string BigNum = Split[0];
        string SmallNum = "0";
        if (Split.Length > 1)
            SmallNum = Split[1];
        int Spot = 0;
        bool FirstD = false;
        string OutBigNum = "";
        for (int Locc = BigNum.Length - 1; Locc >= 0; Locc--)
        {
            Spot++;
            if (FirstD == false)
            {
                OutBigNum = BigNum.Substring(Locc, 1) + OutBigNum;
                FirstD = true;
            }
            else
                OutBigNum = (Spot % 3 == 1 ? "'" : "") + BigNum.Substring(Locc, 1) + OutBigNum;
        }
        Spot = 0;
        FirstD = false;
        string OutSmallNum = "";
        for (int Locc = 0; Locc < SmallNum.Length; Locc++)
        {
            Spot++;
            if (FirstD == false)
            {
                OutSmallNum += SmallNum.Substring(Locc, 1);
                FirstD = true;
            }
            else
            {
                OutSmallNum += (Spot % 3 == 1 ? "," : "") + SmallNum.Substring(Locc, 1);
            }
            if (Locc >= MaxLenPostDec - 1)
                break;
            if (Locc == SmallNum.Length - 1 && MinLenPostDec > Locc)
            {
                for (int Locc2 = Locc; Locc2 < MinLenPostDec - 1; Locc2++)
                {
                    Spot++;
                    OutSmallNum += (Spot % 3 == 1 ? "," : "") + 0;
                }
            }
        }
        CustD = OutBigNum + "." + OutSmallNum;
        return CustD;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that you are not using the correct datatype (decimal) for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'll write down the guy with custom IFormatprovider as the answer though it is not what I wanted.

To Darin, I was using double (3000d) in the example and decimal in my final. I ended up creating my own method, posted following, as I can't think of a current culture that would parse how I want it and be extensively to any lenght.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking into the overload `ToString("#,###.00##", myFormatProvider)`

So you need a [custom IFormatprovider](http://www.csharp-examples.net/custom-iformatprovider/).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would work, but I didn't test it.

```
(3003.3003d).ToString(@"#\'###.00#\,##")
```

Comment: Actually it would be `(3003.3003d).ToString(@"#\'###.00#','##")`. You have to escape the `'` and the `,`

Comment: No problem. You still need the `@` to start the string, otherwise `\,` is an unrecognized escape. :P

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Decimal.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18sthszb.aspx) overload with IFromatProvider. I guess you either want to show to the user currency with a specific (CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture()) or current culture (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).